# Issue in SQL statement to get record combination using "in"

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 2 columns, say Empname, DepartmentName where one employee may work in multiple departments and vice-versa.
I want to write a query to select the EmpName based on some departments combinations.
For ex. The employee who works under Dept1, Dept2 and Dept3 only (it should select only those employees who works under only 3 departments, in this case)

Here is the query I tried.

```
Select EmpName, Count(*) as Total from Emp_Departments where DepartmentName in ('Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3') group by EmpName having Total=3
```

Here the problem is, Any employees who are working any of the above mentioned departments and their total count is 3, it returns their rows also.
Please suggest how can I get the unique combinations only.

Comment: What is the structure of your table? Is `EmpName` unique? Is the combination `EmpName`,`DepartmentName` also unique?

Comment: Yes the combination of EmpName and Department are unqiue

Comment: What about `EmpName` alone? Is that unique?

Comment: No, Empname is repeating as one empname can associate with multiple depatnames.

Comment: In that case you will not be able to achieve what you want. You will need a unique field to differentiate between two employees who have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close - use:

```
  SELECT d.EmpName, COUNT(*) as Total 
    FROM Emp_Departments d
   WHERE d.DepartmentName IN ('Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3') 
GROUP BY d.EmpName 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.DepartmentName) = 3
```

Comment: This will not work because the OP mentioned `EmpName` is not unique

Comment: @zi42: Irrelevant -- that is the column that is being grouped by.

Comment: OK. I thought he was trying to differentiate many employees under the same name which would not have made sense either way.

Comment: @OMGPonies It is showing more irrelevant records which have more than 3 records also.

Comment: @Ajay: Yes, it will show those with duplicates, but only duplicates of the department names in the `IN` clause.  Your table needs a unique constraint on the employee & department name columns...